Old movie of newlyweds in haunted hotel
I'm trying to find a movie.

It's an old movie, probably around 80's-90's maybe.
It's a comedy horror, not scary just the concept of the haunted hotel.
I think there are two newlywed couples
One husband turns into a ghost or becomes invisible. I remember a scene where his wife was putting makeup and dressing up while insulting him, and he was standing next to her but she couldn't see him.
Somewhere towards the end the husband (don't know which) meets this ghost girl I suppose who suddenly turns from pretty to old and skeleton like

That's all I remember. I hope someone would know it.

80s-90s qualifies as old?

It's High Spirits, a 1988 comedy with Peter O'Toole, Steve Guttenberg, Daryl Hannah and others.

When Peter Plunkett's Irish castle turned hotel is about to be repossesed, he decides to spice up the attraction a bit for the 'Yanks' by having his staff pretend to haunt the castle. The trouble begins when a busload of American tourists arrive - along with some real ghosts. Among the tourists are married couple Jack and Sharon. Sharon's father holds the mortgage on Castle Plunkett, so she's hoping to debunk the ghosts.

Both of the scenes you've described are there. Here's the trailer:




omg thank you soooo much!!! i've been looking for this since i was a little kid when i saw it on tv.
